# cross_val_score and LassoCV.score() produce different r2 scores

Tags: python, cross-validation, lasso-regression, k-fold

I thought those two methods should produce similar scores but then I got different scores. Here are my codes:

```
#prepare the data and model
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,train_size = 0.7,test_size = 0.3,random_state = 10)
kf = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.1)
lassocv = LassoCV(cv=kf)
```

And from following code I found very different scores:

```
#see the scores
print(np.mean(cross_val_score(lasso, X_train, Y_train, scoring='r2',
                     cv=kf, n_jobs=-1)))
#score above is 0.18371746011784781

lassocv.fit(X_train,Y_train)
print(lassocv.score(X_train,Y_train))
#the score above is 0.30164049053598596
```

BTW, both the scores of cross_val_score and .score() will fluctuate if I delete the random_state=10 when I split train and test data, but cross_val_score always gets a lower r2 score than .score().

Thanks for your help!